# Adding sample_weight to existing tf Dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow

If I already made a tf dataset and don't have access to the original x and y numpy arrays, how do I add sample_weight to that dataset without having to convert back to numpy again?  Right now I'm trying to concantenate with another dataset with only sample weights as an element, but I'm getting an error.

```
sample_weight_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((None, None, [0.5 for i in range(len(X_train))]))

x_y_dataset.concatenate(sample_weight_dataset)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-128-d5022ef19aff> in <module>()
----> 1 train_dataset.concatenate(sample_weight_dataset)

1 frames
google3/third_party/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py in __init__(self, input_dataset, dataset_to_concatenate)
   4309       raise TypeError(
   4310           "Two datasets to concatenate have different types %s and %s" %
-> 4311           (output_types, get_legacy_output_types(dataset_to_concatenate)))
   4312 
   4313     output_classes = get_legacy_output_classes(input_dataset)

TypeError: Two datasets to concatenate have different types (tf.float64, tf.float64) and (NoneTensorSpec(), NoneTensorSpec(), tf.float32)
```